# Convert PHP Json to jquery format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I make this function in php, but i want to make now in Jquery, is the same process to build a this json format in jquery?
I need the same format like this PHP, but now in jquery

```
$json_full =  array();

  $json= (object) array (
            "salutation"=>'test' ,
            "title"=>'test' ,
            "first_name"=>'test' ,
            "last_name"=>'test' ,
            "street"=>'test' ,
            "street_number"=>'test' ,
            "address_supplement"=>'test' ,
            "zipcode"=>'test' ,
            "city"=>'test' ,
            "country"=>'test' ,
            "terms_accepted"=>true,   
            "receiving_mails_accepted"=>'test' ,  
            "email"=>'test' ,
            "lottery_accepted"=> false,
            "lottery_solution"=> "LOTTERY",
            "original_created_at"=>'test' ,
           );

            $json->items = (object )array (
               'campaign_number' =>'test' ,
               'item_number' =>'test' , 

            );

  array_push($json_full, $json);

print_r(json_encode($json_full));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can do this:

```
var json = { // Create object
    "salutation" : "test",
    "title" : "test",
    "lottery_accepted" : true, // Boolean
    "items" : [{ // Array of objects
          "campaign_number" : "test",
          "item_number" : "test"
    }],
    ...
};
var jsonfull = []; // Push to jsonfull.
jsonfull.push(json);
```

Convert to string:

```
JSON.stringify(json);
```